# Is $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ bijective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ via $f(x) = \frac {x^2}{1+x^2}$

Injective:
Suppose f(a) = f(b)
$$ \implies \frac {a^2}{1+a^2} = \frac {b^2}{1+b^2} \implies a^2 +a^2b^2 = b^2 +b^2a^2$$

$$ \implies a^2 = b^2 \implies a \neq b$$

Surjective: If $x<0$, the image of $f$ is $[0, \infty)$
Hence $f$ is not surjective.

Therefore, $f$ is neither injective or surjective.

Comment: $x=\pm1$.......

Comment: a^2=b^2 implies a=b or a=-b. f (1)=f (-1).

Comment: It's even. How could it be injective?

Comment: @zhw. i didnt say its injective

Comment: If it's bijective, it's injective.

Comment: @zhw. when did i say its bijective, unless u meant in the title, if so i meant if the function is bijective

Comment: I'm saying this: If it's bijective, then it's injective. But this function is even, therefore it's not injective. And therefore it's not bijective.

Comment: You almost had it: $\dots \iff a^2 = b^2 \iff  a = \pm b$ - not injective

Comment: The image of $f$ is actually $[0,1)$, not $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f $ is an even function
$$\implies f (1)=f (-1)=\frac {1}{2} $$

$\implies f $ is not injective

$\implies f $ is not bijective.

Comment: okay so how did u get  $a=-b$?

Comment: @TheGamer a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b )